# Не работает success, почему?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Код:Js, jQuery, Ajax

```
<script>
    function before () {
            $("#information").text("Подождите...");
    }
    function after(data) {
            $("#information").text(data);
    }

    $(document).ready (function () {
        $("#load").bind("click", function () {
            var admin = "Admin";
            $.ajax ({
                url: "test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: ({name: admin, number: 4}),
                dataType: "text",
                beforeSend: before ,
                success: after
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Код:HTML

```
<body>
    <p id="load" style="cursor:pointer;">Загрузить</p>
    <div id="information"></div>
</body>
```

Код:Php

```
<?php
    sleep(2);
    echo "Имя: ".$_POST['name'].", Цифра: ".$_POST['number'];
?>
```

Браузер выдает ошибку:

> jquery.min.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///P:/home/html.loc/www/test.php.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59776/discussion-on-question-by-----success-).

Answer (score 0):

надо открывать файлы на локальном сервере без **file:///** в начале пути, **http://www** правильное начало пути к файлу.